# Permissions for AWS EC2 apache webserver root

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a WordPress blog on an AWS EC2 server. I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html) tutorial from AWS for configuring the web root `/var/www/html` permissions to directories 2775 and files 0664 with ownership `apache:apache`, and I was able to install my site and edit it through wordpress normally.

However, last week I noticed odd behavior on the site and upon looking at the web root, I found a new directory had been created that was full of spammy php files. The directory had a random name and ownership `apache:apache`

This is a webserver, so it has 0.0.0.0 access on ports 80 and 442 (I have SSL through LetsEncrypt and HSTS).

My question is: how was someone able to create a new directory on my server and how do I prevent it from happening in the future? My ec2-user uses an SSH key for login and I have not created any other users on the server. I know now that 775 is probably too open, but if `apache` does not have a login how could someone write to this directory?

Answer (score 2):

You can set in-bound rules on your instance security group to access or allow SSH using your IP address to prevent other attack and make sure you can use a nulled or hack script on the website.

Comment: I do have that set up already. SSH access is only available to my current IP address, and the only other access to the server is open access on ports 80 and 443 for users to view and interact with my site. But even with those restrictions, I still had the issue described above which I'm hoping to understand and avoid.

Comment: Then might be on your website have some backlinks or upload function that was not filtering security then only happen.